# Should CardView always wrap a layout first?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-cardview

I have a cardview with only one textview.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:foreground="@drawable/selector_normal"
    android:clickable="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_command"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_standard"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_standard"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLightBlue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium_small" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Apparently the LinearLayout does nothing other than wrapping the TextView. However if I remove the LinearLayout, having the CardView wrap just the TextView, my entire TextView disappear. Is this not allowed?

Is it possible to remove the LinearLayout?

**I want to reduce my layout hierarchy by removing redundant layout.**

Comment: Well a simple question to you "Did you try to do it ?"

Comment: @RakshitNawani OP mentioned that he **did** do it. But apparently his TextView disappeared.

Comment: After removing the `LinearLayout` you will have to change the `layout_width` to either `match_parent` or `wrap_content` and remove the now obsolete `layout_weight` attribute

Comment: Well if you remove your LL then you should also add the   android:layout_width according to your need not 0dp

Comment: After removal of LL textview doest disapper. check below answer.I have tried.

Comment: I did do it. But didn't remove 0dp. on my TextView layout_width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, it is not necessary** to have LinearLayout above than android.support.v7.widget.CardView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="@drawable/selector_normal"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_command"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" //change here to match_parent
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_standard"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_standard"
        android:textColor="@color/colorLightBlue"
        android:hint="Your Text Here"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium_small"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thanks!! Apparently I forget to change the TextView layout_width="0dp", which makes it disappear.

Comment: Don't think my question deserve a -1 though :( ... as it's a valid question, and others could face this issue. Your answer would be helpful to others to notice this issue. So I have upvote and tick your answer. Thanks!